# Can an IC be programmed by an Arduino and then be removed, to be used in an external breadboard?

Tags: arduino-ide

I wanted to find out if is possible to write programs into a micro controller using the Arduino and use the micro controller independent of the Arduino board?

Comment: yes ...........

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The compiles code will is burned in the Arduino ROM. You can then take the Atmel chip (the Arduino microprocessor) and use it. You only need a few extra component for a chip like the 328p (Arduino Uno).

[image]

Comment: That design also needs 0.1uF caps from the VCC, AVCC, and Aref pins to Gnd.

Answer (score 0):

For another example, using another method, an Uno can program another MCU without the target needing any bootloader, thus enabling your code to occupy the entire Flash memory of the target devices. Here is a link describing how to program an Attiny using an Uno and the ArduinoISP example program. An Attiny85, for example, has 8K of flash, all of which is usable by your application, using this technique. For comparison, a bootloader in an Attiny85 takes about 2.5K, or 30% of the Flash space! And it only gets worse with the smaller Attinys.